# Template specialization vs using if else on template parameter type

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Suppose we have a templated function in which a tiny part of code is dependent on the template parameter type. From design POV(or from any POV for that matter), which one is better! Using if else check on the parameter type by using `type_traits` (we could use `is_same`) or template specialization(We can put that tiny part in another function which we can specialize) ?

```
template <typename T>
void func(T log) {
    // common part

    // part dependent on T. We can put this in a separate function which we can specialize.
    // or we can do:
    // if (std::is_same<T, type1>::value) {
    //    //code1;
    // } else if (std::is_same<T, type2>::value) {
    //    //code2;
    // } else {
    //    //generic code;
    // }

    // common part
}
```

Comment: Please give examples for both. Try to avoid the impression of asking a mostly opinion-based question.

Comment: Using if-else on type is always a bad choice (it tend to make your code fragile and a maintenance nightmare). Specialization, overloading or inheritance/polymorphism is always the better choice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you please elaborate the reason for that design choice?

Comment: @Yunnosch Why do you think that this is mostly opinion-based? A design is either good XOR bad universally.

Comment: *"A design is either good XOR bad universally."* - Wrong. Different applications have different considerations. A design that is horrible for one may be just the ticket for another. That's why any discussion of design lists alternatives, along with pros and cons of each.

Comment: Most sane compilers will optimize away the invariant `if`s. The end result will probably be exactly the same. What is "better" depends on your situation.

Comment: @rustyx Yeah, I am more concerned about the design rather than performance which will most likely be the same for both the cases

Comment: constexpr if is prefered when specializing template method of a template class

Answer (score 2):

Using the run time `if` is a bad idea, because everything is already known to compile time. That exactly is the reason why c++ introduced `constexpr if` for that case you mention. `constexpr if` needs a c++17 compliant compiler, which should be the case in 2018 :-)

```
template <typename T>
void func(T ) {
    std::cout << "common before" << std::endl;

     if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
         std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
     } else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, double>::value) {
         std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
     } else {
         std::cout << "other" << std::endl;
     }

     std::cout << "common after" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    func(1);
    func(1.1);
    func('a');
}
```

But there is a point you should mention: If you have a big "common" part in your templated function, doesn't matter if you template specialization or `constexpr if`, you get a full copy of that code for every template instance. So it is a good idea to move that code to a function, to get the common part only once. If the compiler sees that inlining that code is a good choice, it will do it and you get the best of both solutions.

Comment: correct but, IMHO, you should also explicit that `if constexpr` is available starting from C++17.

Comment: @max66: Yes, I would add it. Asking a question in 2018 for c++ is meaning c++17 standard. If not, people should tag with older c++ standard version. That is what I read from time to time here on SO.